# How to display html as text inside EXTJS combo box

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Paste the code blow inside [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home). Look at the item that reads ProblemElement.

```
Ext.define('DropDownList', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    editable: false,

    alias: 'widget.dropdownlist',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent([arguments]);
    },
    onRender: function() {
        this.callParent();

    }
});


var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data: [

        {
            "name": "Alabama"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Alaska"
        }, 
        {
            "name": " <input value='ProblemElement'>"
        }
    ]
});

Ext.application({

    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {


        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {

            items: [{
                xtype: 'dropdownlist',
                hideLabel: false,
                title: 'ComboBox Test',
                fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
                store: states,
                displayField: 'name',
                htmlEncode: true,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            }]

        });
    }
});
```

The problem I am facing is that the item displayed in the dropdown is being rendered as HTML. However after I select it it displays correctly as text (`<input value='ProblemElement'>`), the way I want it.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a contrived example of real problem...?

Comment: Yes. But If you can solve this I could apply the same principle to the bigger problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dropdown list is actually a [Boundlist](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList), and how item text is displayed is controlled by its [`getInnerTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-method-getInnerTpl) method. You can customize the combo's dropdown with [`listConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig) so that the inner text is passed through [`Ext.String.htmlEncode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.String-method-htmlEncode):

```
listConfig: {
    getInnerTpl: function(displayField) {
        return '{[Ext.String.htmlEncode(values.' + displayField + ')]}';
    }
}
```

Full example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rkk